# instantiating a static object in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all its late and I think tiredness is adding to this but I cant get this php to work

I have a Users Class and in a function to find users by an id and then create the person as an object. I'm trying to create this object in a `foreach` loop to get all users from an array of ids so i can then extract each users email

```
foreach ($_GET['CaseStaffs'] as $admin ) {
    $user = Users::find_by_ips_id( $admin['EmployeeId'] );
    $return['staffEmail'][] = $user->email;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

`$_GET['CaseStaffs']` is a json array of staff member ids i'm getting from an api call

each loop it seams to me creating the object but if i try and access any value from the object i get

> Trying to get property of non-object

this is in the line `$return['staffEmail'][] = $user->email;`

var dump of `$admin['EmployeeId']`

```
  {"readyState":4,"responseText":"string(2) \"32\"\nstring(1) \"9\"\nstring(2) \"67\"\nstring(3) \"180\"\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
  api_test.php:127 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"string(2) \"10\"\nstring(1) \"7\"\nstring(2) \"92\"\nstring(3) \"148\"\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

var dump of `$user`

```
  api_test.php:127 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"object(Users)#7 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(1) \"5\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(26) \"r.dymond@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$ZDNjMjU5YzkzMDQ5NzVjYehhZu1P300eGVpLS.prOwxTPeIiN8vQO\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(3) \"Mr.\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(6) \"Robert\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(6) \"Dymond\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"10\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-04-05 00:00:00\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"YThkNjBjYTdmNmE5YzFjZTY4MGNkMmE5NjVkY2I0MWM=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\nobject(Users)#8 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(1) \"7\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(25) \"f.grant@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$ZDNjMjU5YzkzMDQ5NzVjYehhZu1P300eGVpLS.prOwxTPeIiN8vQO\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(5) \"Fiona\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(5) \"Grant\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"10\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-04-05 00:00:00\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"Mjk5MmMwMzYyNWQ5OGQ5YTZhODQ1NjRjYTA2N2FkNDc=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\nbool(false)\n<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\\Users\\jfiel\\Desktop\\document.center.new\\httpdocs\\ajax\\process\\cases.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />\nobject(Users)#7 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(2) \"18\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(27) \"J.Dobbins@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$NTFmNDY2NDBiMDk1MTcyNuLBr325ypXGFIoFxpeCPPhPFpv7lqjXq\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(3) \"Mr.\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(6) \"Joseph\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(7) \"Dobbins\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"30\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-04-06 11:57:52\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"M2Y0MTVmOGRkZTRkNDIyNDg5MWI4MmRlMzEyNzk5NzM=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
api_test.php:127 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"object(Users)#7 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(1) \"8\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(27) \"g.roberts@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$ZDNjMjU5YzkzMDQ5NzVjYehhZu1P300eGVpLS.prOwxTPeIiN8vQO\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(5) \"Gemma\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(7) \"Roberts\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"10\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-04-05 00:00:00\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"OTI1Njk0MWM0YTc1MDE1ZTlmNjg1NWUzOTkxZDk0Zjc=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\nobject(Users)#8 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(2) \"10\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(25) \"e.bower@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$ZDNjMjU5YzkzMDQ5NzVjYehhZu1P300eGVpLS.prOwxTPeIiN8vQO\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(4) \"Emma\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(5) \"Bower\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"10\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-04-04 00:00:00\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"YzA1NGQwOWIzM2VmM2E2NWJkMmE0ZWMxYzQ5ZDdlYTM=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\nbool(false)\n<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\\Users\\jfiel\\Desktop\\document.center.new\\httpdocs\\ajax\\process\\cases.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />\nobject(Users)#7 (15) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  string(3) \"319\"\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(26) \"d.massey@wilsonfield.co.uk\"\n  [\"pwd\"]=>\n  string(60) \"$2y$10$Y2QyODdiMTc0ODA0ZDdmM.rMoco6Oy5JyPsOHudcDljXnsjvgUnWy\"\n  [\"salutation\"]=>\n  string(3) \"Mr.\"\n  [\"first\"]=>\n  string(6) \"Daniel\"\n  [\"last\"]=>\n  string(6) \"Massey\"\n  [\"status\"]=>\n  string(1) \"1\"\n  [\"account\"]=>\n  string(2) \"30\"\n  [\"optin\"]=>\n  string(1) \"0\"\n  [\"rep\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"company_name\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n  [\"reg\"]=>\n  string(19) \"2017-06-05 16:04:58\"\n  [\"token\"]=>\n  string(44) \"YTJmZDdhNDIzZjcyODA5NjFkMzBhMDhiMzlmMTg5MDA=\"\n  [\"assigned\"]=>\n  NULL\n  [\"date\"]=>\n  NULL\n}\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: var_dump $user and $admin['EmployeeId'] and post the result

Comment: var dump for EmplyeeId is   {"readyState":4,"responseText":"string(2) \"32\"\nstring(1) \"9\"\nstring(2) \"67\"\nstring(3) \"180\"\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
  api_test.php:127 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"string(2) \"10\"\nstring(1) \"7\"\nstring(2) \"92\"\nstring(3) \"148\"\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: please post it into your question and not into a comment, it's not readable

Comment: did you decode the json first? I looks like it's a json string...

Comment: i tried  by doing json_decode() but that returns null

Comment: Can you please do a echo gettype($_GET['CaseStaffs']) before the loop and the same for '$admin' inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$admin['EmployeeId']` looks suspicious to me, because `$admin` is each of the values in `$_GET['CaseStaffs']`.

It is already quite uncommon to see URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/file.php?CaseStaffs[]=1&CaseStaffs[]=2&CaseStaffs[]=3
```

Much more to see this (I don't know if this syntax is valid):

```
http://example.com/file.php?CaseStaffs[]['EmployeeId']=1&CaseStaffs[]['EmployeeId']=2&CaseStaffs[]['EmployeeId']=3
```

Use the first URL in the GET request and then, in your code, use this line:

```
$user = Users::find_by_ips_id( $admin );
```

Also, as a side note, you should retrieve all your users at once, or at least in batches. Doing it one by one can easily become a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what is returned from the function api calls are json string, not php array or objects. Use json_decode() to convert it into an Object.

There is nothing called 'EmployeeId' in this json. its a list of ID in the response string.

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"string(2) \"32\"\nstring(1) \"9\"\nstring(2) \"67\"\nstring(3) \"180\"\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

You will have to

```
$jsonarray = json_decode($_GET['CaseStaffs'],true);
$listofIDs = $jsonarray['responseText']; // to get the list of IDs, as string
```

But the string is going to look like:

string(2) "32"
string(1) "9"
string(2) "67"
string(3) "180"

So you will have to figure out how to extract the IDs from the string

Play around with this: https://tehplayground.com/murZXZSWQdCPBZHj